# Forbidden errors at app initialization when using spring cloud vault

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

Using Spring Cloud HOXTON.SR6, with Spring boot 2.3.2

When initiating the service, i get 403 errors trying to access "/secret/application" and "/secret/application/{profile}". The "application" in those paths should be replaced by my application name.

Error:

```
[RequestedSecret [path='secret/application/{profile}’, mode=ROTATE]] Lease [leaseId='null', leaseDuration=PT0S, renewable=false] Status 403 Forbidden [secret/application/{profile}]: 1 error occurred: * permission denied ; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: [{"errors":["1 error occurred:\n\t* permission denied\n\n"]} ] org.springframework.vault.VaultException: Status 403 Forbidden [secret/application/{profile}]: 1 error occurred: * permission denied ; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: [{"errors":["1 error occurred:\n\t* permission denied\n\n"]} ]
```

The replacement works correctly and the erros are gone if i set spring.cloud.vault.generic.enabled = false.
The problem is that this property is set for deprecation. Then what would be the way around it?

The errors are present with:

```
spring:
    cloud:
        vault:
            authentication: approle
            app-role:
                role-id: <<role-id>>
                secret-id: <<secret-id>>
            kv:
                enabled: true
                backend: secret
                application-name: <<application-name>>
                default-context: <<application-name>>
            host: <<vault-host>>
```

But not anymore with:

```
spring:
    cloud:
        vault:
            authentication: approle
            app-role:
                role-id: <<role-id>>
                secret-id: <<secret-id>>
            kv:
                enabled: true
                backend: secret
                application-name: <<application-name>>
                default-context: <<application-name>>
            generic:
                enabled: false
            host: <<vault-host>>
```

Should i be using this differently?

Answer (score 1):

I had kind of a similar problem, and here's what I did :

- I removed *bootstrap.properties* (if any ... as it's deprecated), and moved all the Vault-related props into *application.properties*
- **I declared the property `spring.config.import: vault://` into *application.property***
- I removed `spring.cloud.vault.generic.enabled` (as no longer needed).

*One last thing ... if you're using env. variables, you've to make sure they're really **exported** ... if not, use the source command (or reboot the os)*

Answer (score 0):

As you said setting the generic to false solve the problem, so my recommendation is to keep that until they remove it