# I am using hashicorp vault with springboot maven to store my databse credentials. Getting 403 Permission denied while trying to access the vault

Tags: spring-boot, maven, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

Note : Vault is managed by different team in my project.
Below is my boorstrap.yml config

```
spring:
    application:
       name: MongoSecrets

profiles:
   active: dev
cloud:
   vault:
      enabled: true
      uri: https://vaulturl:443
      scheme: https
       token: "LDAP token"
       kv:
          enaled: true
           backend: MySecrets
       ssl:
           trust-store: cacerts
```

Dependencies used - spring-cloud-starter-vault-config, spring-cloud-dependencies

Received access to MySecrets folder from Vault team. Below is the policies set for the folder

```
path "MySecrets/*" {capabilities= ["create","read","update","delete","list"]}
```

Below is the exception i am getting:

```
org.springframework.vault.authentication.LifecycleAwareSessionManager : Scheduling Token renewal
  org.springframework.vault.core.lease.SecretLeaseEventPublisher$LoggingErrorListener : [RequestedSecret [path='secret/MySecrets/dev', mode=ROTATE]] Lease [leaseId='null', leaseDuration=PT0S, renewable=false] Status 403 FORBIDDEN secrets/MySecrets/dev: 1 error occurred:
  | * permission denied
  |  
  |  
  | org.springframework.vault.VaultException: Status 403 FORBIDDEN secret/MySecrets/dev: 1 error occurred:
  | * permission denied
```

Comment: I am able to successfully connect if i use spring.cloud.vault.generic props instead of  spring.cloud.vault.kv.

But spring.cloud.vault.generic - This depricated in favour of kv

Comment: Here's a link that - I hope - can help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72553127/16803868

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
generic:  
  enabled: false    
kv:  
 enabled: true
```

Changing bootstrap to above worked for me. Seems there was some issue in the way my Client has set up Vault policies. By Default Generic backends are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Your bootstrap.yml is wrong, there is an indentation problem and you misspelled one property.

```
   kv:
      enaled: true
       backend: MySecrets
```

Should be:

```
   kv:
      enabled: true
      backend: MySecrets
```

But spring will still log some errors, as it tries different combinations of profile, app, and backend during startup.

Comment: i modified the path as well but still i was getting the same error. I was able to resolve when i changed spring:cloud:vault:kv  --to--   spring:cloud:vault:generic.

Comment: But "generic" seems to be depricated in favour of "kv". No idea why its failing with "kv" i am still researching. For time being i am using this "generic"