# Spring Cloud Vault Secret reading error as permission denied

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-vault-config, spring-vault

I am unable to read secrets with vault when I upgrade spring version from 2.0.3.RELEASE to 2.3.5.RELEASE
It works fine with 2.0.3.RELEASE (with secret path, secret/data/{app-name}), but with 2.3.5.RELEASE, path is changed to secret/data/data/{app-name} which is causing 403.

LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource  : **Vault location [secret/data/{app-name}**]
not resolvable: **Status 403 Forbidden [**secret/data/data/{app-name}**]**: 1 error occurred: * permission denied

HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: [{"errors":["1 error occurred:\n\t* permission denied\n\n"]}
]
org.springframework.vault.VaultException: Status 403 Forbidden [**secret/data/data/{app-name}**]: 1 error occurred:
* permission denied; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden:
[{"errors":["1 error occurred:\n\t* permission denied\n\n"]}
]

Comment: Here's a link that - I hope - can help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72553127/16803868